# How to use Component Object Model in Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, com

I would like to use the CoCreateInstance() function, here is the msdn doc :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wad1c0e%28VS.80%29.aspx

I can see that I should include Objbase.h from Ole32.lib library, but I don't know how to do this in Visual C++ Express 2008 (I use Windows XP so I can't use a more recent version).

Does anyone may help me ?

Thanks

Comment: It worked... I thought I tried it but it seems that I didn't... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Objbase.h and Ole32.lib are from Windows SDK. You can use them and CoCreateInstance() in Visual C++ Express 2008 if Windows SDK is installed with it.

The MSDN link in your question uses C++ library ATL. It can simplify the code for COM, but not include in Express version.

Without ATL, you can do the programming with the steps in this article  http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm

Answer (score 0):

`#include <ObjBase.h>` or `#include "ObjBase.h"` in your source file, just like any other include file. `ObjBase.h` should be located in either your INCLUDE or SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you use CoCreateInstance for. For example, when you use IDiscMaster2 interface to enumerate the CD and DVD devices installed on the computer, then you should install this patch https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=17073